# Unable to add new model to Django Postgres DB via migration

Tags: django, postgresql, load

I want to add a new model in my Django project after building my PostgresQL database. I add the model, run makemigations and migrate which both run fine. The model appears in the migrations files, but when I run python manage.py inspectdb it is not there.

My initial import line works. This runs:

```
  from project import model1
```

When I try to load data into this model, I get the following error when I try to add this data from a CSV via get_or_create model.

```
  django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "project_model1" does not exist
```

Not sure how to fix this. Do I need to delete the database and start again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to delete the database to add the new model.

Can you post the code defining the model?

And the steps you took to migrate it?

One issue that it could be a is that you have created many to many view, this deosn't automatically create a database table unless you specify the 'through' parameter:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships